# JNI native method returning a jboolean that is neither JNI_FALSE nor JNI_TRUE

Tags: java, java-native-interface, boolean

If a JNI native function that is supposed to return a boolean (native type jboolean) returns a value that is neither JNI_FALSE (0) nor JNI_TRUE (1), is it defined how Java should interpret the value?

With two different versions of Java I have observed some strange goings-on after returning from a native function that does something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_Class_function(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Typically false is 0 and true is anything else.

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

Comment: To elaborate: Java could evaluate the expression as `(val == 1)`, or as `(val != 0)`, or as `(val | 1)`, or as `((val << 3) | 8)`... or just not evaluate it until much later. The JVM is allowed to be optimized under the assumption that the only possible return values are JNI_FALSE and JNI_TRUE, so bad things could happen if a native function passes back anything else.

Comment: @david `(val | 1)` doesn't make sense, and norr does the one with the shift.